# How to connect Hibernate elasticsearch use SSL with quarkus?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, quarkus, hibernate-search

I connect ES without SSL is success
but when I enabled SSL then error:

file application.yml

```
quarkus:
 ssl:
  native: true
 native: additional-build-args: -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=tls.crt,-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

with tls.crt is file crt

Who help me or suggest keyword this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Please share the error or exception

Comment: @D.T It is text exception   `Unable to detect the Elasticsearch version running on the cluster: HSEARCH400007: Elasticsearch request failed: Connection is closed
Request: GET  with parameters {}
at org.hibernate.search.backend.elasticsearch.client.impl.ElasticsearchClientUtils.getElasticsearchVersion(ElasticsearchClientUtils.java:56)`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.